# Filter SQL rows with non unique IDs on another value

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter, where-clause

I have a quite big SQL request which produces the following statement (simplified for clarity):

[image]

However, I need to filter this result and only get LabIds which have NO CapacityId = 4.
In this sample, the expected result is only LabId 7

Here is a fiddle reproducing the situation: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e581a/2

With this request:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Lab (LabId int, CapacityId int)

INSERT INTO Lab (LabId, CapacityId)
VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1),(2, 2)

SELECT LabId 
FROM Lab 
WHERE CapacityId != 4
GROUP BY LabId
```

It still retrieves both Labs, because both have at least one line where CapacityId != 4

How to should I `WHERE/GROUP BY` to only get Labs which has NO CapacityId = 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `having`:

```
SELECT LabId 
FROM Lab 
GROUP BY LabId
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN CapacityId = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

The `SUM()` adds up the number of rows for each `LabId` that have `4` for the capacity.  The `= 0` specify that there are none.

Note:  This does not returns `LabId`s that have no rows in this table (which also technically meet this condition).  For that, use `NOT EXISTS`.  Let me assume that the tables are named a bit differently:

```
SELECT l.LabId 
FROM Labs l
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM LabCapacity lc
                  WHERE lc.LabId = l.LabId AND
                        lc.CapacityId = 4
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT l1.LabId
FROM Lab l1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Lab l2 WHERE l2.LabId = l1.LabId AND
                                             l2.CapacityId = 4);
```

You may also use aggregation:

```sql
SELECT LabId 
FROM Lab 
GROUP BY LabId
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN CapacityId = 4 THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use analytic function

```
SELECT LabId 
FROM (select labId, CapacityId, 
        sum(case when CapacityId=4 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by labId) cnt_capacyty4
       from Lab
     ) 
WHERE cnt_capacyty4 = 0
GROUP BY LabId
```